# Firestore rules 'allow create' create document with different ID if already exists

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore `allow create` rule that prohibits a document from being created if its ID already exists. What I want to do is to create a new document with a different random ID when this happens.

For instance, I want to create 10 documents with IDs 1,2,3...10. However, IDs 2,3,4 already exist and won't get created, so I want 3 documents with random IDs created (like 11, 12, 13).

How can I accomplish that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Security rules aren't going to be able to help you enforce this.  Also, what you're trying to do is not a very good fit for Firestore, and I'll discuss that as well.

The only way to check the contents of any other document in security rules is with a call to [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) or [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.exists), and you can only call this up to 10 times per rule evaluation.  So, as soon as you get more than 10 documents, you're not going to be able to check enough documents to enforce document ID numbering.

On top of that, Firestore is not well suited for using sequential document IDs at the massive scale that it's intended to operate on.  The preferred approach is to generate random document IDs using add() on the client.  If you need to impose some sort of ordering on those document, you should use a document field value for that, or have another document with an array that defines the order.

If for some reason you have a hard requirement to have strictly sequential document IDs, you might want to rethink why exactly you need this in a NoSQL type database.  It's just not a scalable situation that Firestore intends to solve.

It's also worth nothing that an `allow create` rule would never trigger if a document already exists.  Once a document exists, a client can only update or delete it.  If you want to prevent a client from updating a document that already exists, you'll simply want to make sure that there is no `allow write` or `allow update` rule that allows that update to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Doug. Actually the IDs aren't sequential - I just used that as an example. Basically, my app is a raffle ticketing system, so if a user wants 10 tickets, it'll generate 10 documents with random IDs between 1111111111 and 9999999999. I'm currently using `allow create: if !exists(.../$(id))`

Comment: If you're worried about the client generating a duplicate, then you'll just have to check to see if it exists before writing it.  As I said in the answer, `allow create` will not do anything for existing documents.  You might just need a rule to stop the client from doing anything with the existing documents, but it's hard to tell from what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, that was the original design (checking if exists before creating), but it was getting slow as ticket count grew to over 1000. So if, say 100 people wanted to generate 200 tickets, the system would do an if-exists-generate-another-id-else-create-new 20,000 times. Any suggestions on a better way? Or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: I think you are being paranoid.  Checking and setting documents is not really slow.  That's how Firestore transactions work, and people use them all the time to safely add documents without clobbering existing ones.